# Flutter- came back to previous page

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In my details page there's a button for displaying side menu. I've to go other page by using side menu and came back to Details page. For this I'm using below code.

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Details(id1: widget.items.id1, id2: widget.items.id2,) ),
        (route) => false
);
```

But the problem of using this piece of code is when I'm use go other page and came to Details page multiple times it'll blackout the screen.

Now, how could I route this to came back to my Details page with **MaterialPageRoute()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should simply use `Navigator.push` instead of `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil`.